# PHP : I need to read value from ur "www.smple.com/sample.php/value in php

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, lamp

I need to read the value from url in php code. Below is the sample url . I am passing the value after php file name. 
I know that we can use query string like "www.smple.com/sample.php?name=value"

But requirement is url need to filename/value, this value will be dynamic. 
Please any one can help me to solve this issue.

URL : [www.smple.com/sample.php/value](http://www.smple.com/sample.php/value)

Comment: To be clear: You want to extract the string after the second forward slash?

Comment: Look at `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: Also look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow..What have you tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a clear outline of the exact issue and a summary of what you tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parse_url to get the path from the URL and then use explode to split it into its segments.

```
$uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);

echo $uri_segments[1];
```

Comment: If your work is done with my answer then please accept my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the value is like

```
http://www.example.com?value=42
```

You can read it with

```
$value = $_GET['value'];
```

If the value is like

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/foo
```

where foo is the value, you can read it with $_SERVER variable:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] => localhost
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] => /index.php/foo
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] => GET
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] => /index.php
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] => /Users/sensorario/Development/local/fake-server/web/index.php
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] => /foo
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] => /index.php/foo
```

And also, if you need more information about a request, .. just type

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

to see all the information you can get from current request ^_^

Comment: Thank U Bro. I got it

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right, you want to pass your param as a friendly url. If thats the case fisrt you need to use the re-write mode in either Apache or Nginx so when you get `example.com/xxx/yyy` it sends to php `example.com/xxx?param=yyy` after doing it you can get it with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` as mentioned in answers above/below.

Apache info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html